# How to emit/pipe array values as a readable stream in node.js?

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe

What is the best way to create a readable stream from an array and pipe values to a writable stream? I have seen substack's [example](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) using setInterval and I can implement that successfully using 0 for the interval value, but I am iterating over a lot of data and triggering gc every time is slowing things down.

```
// Working with the setInterval wrapper
var arr = [1, 5, 3, 6, 8, 9];

function createStream () {
    var t = new stream;
    t.readable = true;
    var times = 0;
    var iv = setInterval(function () {
        t.emit('data', arr[times]);
        if (++times === arr.length) {
            t.emit('end');
            clearInterval(iv);
        }
    }
}, 0);

// Create the writable stream s
// ....

createStream().pipe(s);
```

What I would like to do is emit values without the setInterval. Perhaps using the async module like this:

```
async.forEachSeries(arr, function(item, cb) {
    t.emit('data', item);
    cb();
}, function(err) {
 if (err) {
     console.log(err);
 }
 t.emit('end');
});
```

In this case I iterate the array and emit data, but never pipe any values. I have already seen shinout's [ArrayStream](https://github.com/shinout/ArrayStream), but I think that was created before v0.10 and it is a bit more overhead than I am looking for.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get much less overhead than ArrayStream (110 sloc). async is going to be similar to substack's example in it's use of setImmediate. I don't think you need setImmediate/setInterval for every data event since you're not doing IO but you will need to handle pause/resume which ArrayStream does for you. Curious to see what answers you get.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess my biggest concern with ArrayStream was that it had not been updated since the changes in the Stream API in v0.10, but those worries could be unfounded. I was surprised that it had so few downloads which makes me believe that others are doing this differently.

Comment: Please consider unaccepting the accepted answer and accepting the one recommendign the standard `Readable.from`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can solve this problem by creating a readable stream and pushing values into it.

> Streams are a pain, but it's often [easier](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) to [work with them directly](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) than to use libraries.

### Array of strings or buffers to stream

If you're working with an array of strings or buffers, this will work:

```
'use strict'
const Stream = require('stream')
const readable = new Stream.Readable()

readable.pipe(process.stdout)

const items = ['a', 'b', 'c']
items.forEach(item => readable.push(item))

// no more data
readable.push(null)
```

Notes:

- `readable.pipe(process.stdout)` does two things: puts the stream into "flowing" mode and sets up the process.stdout writable stream to receive data from `readable`
- the `Readable#push` method is for the creator of the readable stream, not the stream consumer.
- You have to do `Readable#push(null)` to signal that there is no more data.

### Array of non-strings to stream

To make a stream from an array of things that are neither strings nor buffers, you need both the readable stream and the writable stream to be in ["Object Mode"](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_object_mode). In the example below, I made the following changes:

- Initialize the readable stream with `{objectMode: true}`
- Instead of piping to `process.stdout`, pipe to a simple writable stream that is in object mode.

  ```
    'use strict'
    const Stream = require('stream')

    const readable = new Stream.Readable({objectMode: true})

    const writable = new Stream.Writable({objectMode: true})
    writable._write = (object, encoding, done) => {
      console.log(object)

      // ready to process the next chunk
      done()
    }

    readable.pipe(writable)

    const items = [1, 2, 3]
    items.forEach(item => readable.push(item))

    // end the stream
    readable.push(null)
  ```

### Performance Note

Where is the data coming from? If it's a streaming data source, it's better to manipulate the stream using a transform stream than to convert to/from an array.

Comment: How can we chain the writable from your last exemple ?

Comment: @Gura, what are you trying to do? `readable.pipe(writable).pipe(somethingElse)`? If so, `writable` will have to be a Transform stream. I can add info about that if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: I used Transform, it works very well ! thanks @mheiber

Comment: Fantastic answer, and especially the first resource you linked to. I found it to be incredibly thorough and useful.

Comment: @DaveVoyles-MSFT re the first resource: it's the go-to that everyone recommends, but I found the Node docs themselves invaluable for figuring out everything I needed. In particular, I tend to need transform streams and the handbook doesn't cover those.

Comment: Might be missing to implement `_read()` of the Readable stream. See here for a similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22085851/2012945 (strings to streams).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `readable.push()` call needs to be checking if the streams internal buffer is full, no? Otherwise, there's a risk that some elements in the array don't make it into the stream.

Comment: Is it important to look at the return value of `push()`, and to stop `push()`ing if there is backpressure?

Comment: @bennlich that sounds important. Would you be up for editing the answer if you find a good way to do this?

Answer (score 27):

As of Node 12.3, you can use [`stream.Readable.from(iterable, [options])`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/stream.html#stream_stream_readable_from_iterable_options) instead.

```js
const { Readable } = require("stream");

const arr = [1, 5, 3, 6, 8, 9];
const readableStream = Readable.from(arr);

readableStream.on("data", (row) => console.log(row));
```

It also works with Objects

```js
const arr = [
  { index: 1, hello: { foo: "bar" } },
  { index: 2, hello: { foo: "bar" } },
  { index: 3, hello: { foo: "bar" } },
];
const readableStream = Readable.from(arr);
```

Comment: It should work for an `Iterable` -- do you have an example of it not working for arrays of objects?

Comment: Oh, you're right. I had tried it in something I was working on and it didn't work. I assumed it was because the Readable wasn't in `objectMode`. But I just created a simple example and it worked. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 15):

tl;dr;

This is a LIFO solution. Array.prototype.pop() has similar behavior to shift but applied to the last element in an array.

```
const items = [1,2,3]
const stream = new Readable({
  objectMode: true,
  read() {
    const item = items.pop()
    if (!item) {
      this.push(null);
      return;
    }
    this.push(item)
  },
})
```

Comment: Should we not `shift()`, to send the array in order, instead of `pop()`.

Comment: This is a LIFO solution. Array.prototype.pop() has similar behavior to shift but applied to the last element in an array.

Comment: Would you edit the answer to clarify that? Because all the other answers, and indeed my own expectation coming into this question, are around FIFO.

Answer (score 2):

I wound up using [ArrayStream](https://github.com/shinout/ArrayStream) for this. It did resolve the issue with the GC being triggered too often. I was getting warnings for a recursive process.nextTick from node so modified the nextTick callbacks in ArrayStream to setImmediate and that fixed the warnings and seems to be working well.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but if anyone stumbles on this, [node-stream-array](https://github.com/mimetnet/node-stream-array) is a much simpler and more elegant implementation for Node.js >= v0.10

```
var streamify = require('stream-array'),
  os = require('os');

streamify(['1', '2', '3', os.EOL]).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, node-stream-array does not return a true Readable, and that may cause problem with other parts of the code (ex: missing destroy function when used with promisepipe)

Comment: Just ran into the "not a Readable" issue that Ludovic commented about.  Attempting "for await (const chunk of stream)" results in the following error: "TypeError: stream is not async iterable"