# Node: adding a string as a file into a tar archive (without temporary files)

Tags: javascript, node.js, tar

I would like to make a tar archive in node. The [canonical tar archiving example](https://gist.github.com/nicolasfont/2040815) is based on a file stream:

```
fstream
  .Reader({path: 'src', type: "Directory"})
  .pipe(tar.Pack())
  .pipe(zlib.createGzip())
  .pipe(fstream.Writer("output.tar.gz"));
```

My data is actually in memory as a string, which I would like to write to the archive without having to make a temporary file in between.

Is there some way I can do this, e.g. maybe make an fstream out of a string?

Comment: How to create stream from string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755997/how-to-create-streams-from-string-in-node-js

Answer (score 5):

The [tar-stream](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-stream) module can do this too:

```
var tar = require('tar-stream')    

var content = "whatever string you have"
var pack = tar.pack()
pack.entry({name: 'src', type: 'directory'})
pack.entry({name: 'src/someFile.txt'}, content) // file
pack.finalize()
```

`tar-stream` can also use streams as sources for file contents.

Answer (score 1):

The [tar-async](https://github.com/beatgammit/tar-async) module handles this quite simply, without needing to make fake streams:

```
var uploadArchive = new Tar({output: fs.createWriteStream('archive.tar')});
uploadArchive.append('somefile.txt', 'someString', function() {
  tape.close();
});
```

Comment: so how does one gzip the tar archive?