# How do I turn a String into a Readable Stream?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to stream a string to another stream:

```
streamer = new stream.Transform objectMode: true
stringer = (string) ->
    streamer._transform = (chunk, encoding, done) ->
        @push string.split('').shift()
        done()

    return streamer

streamer.on 'readable', ->
    console.log 'readable'

stringer('hello').pipe process.stdout
```

But nothing logs in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755997/how-to-create-streams-from-string-in-node-js

Comment: The source code of [`string-stream`](https://github.com/mikanda/string-stream/blob/master/index.js) could be as reference..

Comment: Note: The code in this question is CoffeeScript, not JavaScript.

Comment: @Markasoftware when I run the code in that example i get this error: `_stream_readable.js:480
  dest.on('unpipe', onunpipe);
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`

Comment: This question really needs to be closed. It already has answers at the link I posted, and there are other resources that show how to do the exact same thing on other sites as well.

Comment: Dont be sore because someone downvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need as you say yourself is a readable stream not a transformation stream. Additionally you have a bug because `string.split('')` always return the same Array and then `.shift()` will always return the same letter. Your code once rewritten is as follows:

```
'use strict'

Readable = require('stream').Readable

stringer = (string) ->
  array = string.split('')
  new Readable
    read: (size) ->
      @push array.shift()
      return

readable = stringer('hello')

readable.on 'readable', ->
  console.log 'readable'
  return

readable.pipe process.stdout
```

Answer (score 16):

In Node 10.x, the [`Readable.from`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/stream.html#readable.from) convenience method was added, making this far more straightforward to accomplish.

```js
const Readable = require('stream').Readable;

Readable.from('hello').pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 3):

If your end goal is to turn a string into a readable stream, simply use the module [into-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/into-stream).

```
var intoStream = require('into-stream')
intoStream('my-str').pipe(process.stdout)
```

---

If on the other hand, you want to know a way to actually do this yourself, the source code for that module is a little bit obtuse and so I'll create an example:

(You don't actually need a transform stream as in your code, just a writable stream)

```
var chars = 'my-str'.split('')
  , Stream = require('stream').Readable

new Stream({ read: read }).pipe(process.stdout)

function read(n) {
  this.push(chars.shift())
}
```

**Note.** This will only work with Node version >= 4. Previous versions didn't have the convenience methods in the `Stream` constructor. For older Nodes (0.10.x, 0.12.x etc.) the following slightly longer example will work…

```
var chars = 'my-str'.split('')
  , Stream = require('stream').Readable
  , s = new Stream()

s._read = function (n) {
  this.push(chars.shift())
}

s.pipe(process.stdout)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to work. I'm not really familiar with all the new JavaScript syntax in ES6 and ES7 that you're using in your question, so I just rewrote this from scratch:

```
const util=require('util');
const stream=require('stream');

var StringStream=function(strArg){
    stream.Readable.call(this);
    this.str=strArg.split('');
}

util.inherits(StringStream,stream.Readable);

StringStream.prototype._read=function(numRead){
    this.push(this.str.splice(0,numRead).join(''));
}

var thisIsAStringStream=new StringStream('this-is-test-text-1234567890');
thisIsAStringStream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

On my system it outputs `this-is-test-text-1234567890`, so it is working correctly. This works exactly how it is recommended in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_implementors)
, by creating a class that extends the `stream.Readable` class using `util.inherit`, calling the constructor of `stream.Readable` inside of the constructor for the new class by doing `stream.Readable.call('this')`, and implementing the `_read` method to output characters from the string using `this.push`.

In case it's not clear, the way you would use this is by creating the stream using something like this:

```
var helloWorldStream=new StringStream('HelloWorld');
```

And then you can use the stream as you would any readable stream.

Comment: I've found examples like this that use inheritance, its too mangled of a solution. Is there a functional approach to using streams? Something along the lines of, `require('stream')(string).push('hello').pipe(process.stdout)`?

Comment: This is literally the official way to create a custom readable stream. I might look into something later today, but yeah.