# How to index a JSON document directly from memory

Tags: json, node.js, watson, watson-discovery

I'm trying to index a JSON document, but it simply isn't working; so far, I have tried the solutions posted in https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/361808/adding-a-json-document-to-a-discovery-collection-u/ , but it simply does not work;

If I try:

```
    discovery.addDocument({
        environment_id: config.watson.environment_id,
        collection_id: config.watson.collection_id,
        file: JSON.stringify({
            "ocorrencia_id": 9001
        })
    }, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }

        console.log(data);
    });
```

It returns me this error:

```
    The Media Type [text/plain] of the input document is not supported. Auto correction was attempted, but the auto detected media type [text/plain] is also not supported. Supported Media Types are: application/json, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/pdf, text/html, application/xhtml+xml .
```

On the other hand, if I try:

```
    discovery.addDocument({
        environment_id: config.watson.environment_id,
        collection_id: config.watson.collection_id,
        file: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
            "ocorrencia_id": 9001
        }))
    }, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }

        console.log(data);
    });
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: source.on is not a function
    at Function.DelayedStream.create (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:33:10)
    at FormData.CombinedStream.append (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:43:37)
    at FormData.append (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\form-data\lib\form_data.js:68:3)
    at appendFormValue (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\request\request.js:324:21)
    at Request.init (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\request\request.js:337:11)
    at new Request (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\request\request.js:130:8)
    at request (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\request\index.js:54:10)
    at createRequest (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\watson-developer-cloud\lib\requestwrapper.js:177:10)
    at DiscoveryV1.addDocument (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\watson-developer-cloud\discovery\v1.js:516:10)
    at client.query.then.res (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\populate\populate.js:36:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Similarly, by saving to a temp file, and then using it:

```
    const tempy = require('tempy');
    const f = tempy.file({extension: 'json'});
    fs.writeFileSync(f, JSON.stringify({
            "ocorrencia_id": 9001
    }));

    discovery.addDocument({
        environment_id: config.watson.environment_id,
        collection_id: config.watson.collection_id,
        file: fs.readFileSync(f)
    }, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }

        console.log(data);
    });
```

Then this happens:

```
The Media Type [application/octet-stream] of the input document is not supported. Auto correction was attempted, but the auto detected media type [text/plain] is also not supported. Supported Media Types are: application/json, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/pdf, text/html, application/xhtml+xml .
```

Considering other posts recommend using JSON.parse(), it seems that the API accepts a JS object, but none of the examples, and nothing that I have tried so far seems to be working. Seems to be a bug?

Update: by saving into a temp file and then using `createDataStream()`, instead of `readFileSync()`, it works, but it is still a big bother having to got through the disk for an information that's already on memory.

I have also tried to [create a in-memory stream from a Readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755997/how-to-create-streams-from-string-in-node-js), but that fails, too:

```
    var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
    var s = new Readable();
    s._read = function noop() {}; // redundant? see update below
    s.push(JSON.stringify({
            "ocorrencia_id": 9001
    }));        
    s.push(null);

    discovery.addDocument({
        environment_id: config.watson.environment_id,
        collection_id: config.watson.collection_id,
        file: s
    }, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }

        console.log(data);
    });
```

This one fails with:

```
Error: Unexpected end of multipart data
    at Request._callback (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\watson-developer-cloud\lib\requestwrapper.js:88:15)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\request\request.js:1171:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (C:\Temp\teste-watson\watson-orchestrator\node_modules\request\request.js:1091:12)
    at Gunzip.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9) code: 500, error: 'Unexpected end of multipart data'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service checks filename and then content to determine type, but doesn't seem to recognize JSON content correctly - it just sees text. The other answer will work, as long as the filename ends in `.json` (it does not care about the contentType).

However, we added [`.addJsonDocument()`](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/node-sdk/v2.37.0/DiscoveryV1.html#addJsonDocument) and [`.updateJsonDocument()`](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/node-sdk/v2.37.0/DiscoveryV1.html#updateJsonDocument) methods to the node.js SDK to make it even easier:

```
discovery.addJsonDocument({
    environment_id: config.watson.environment_id,
    collection_id: config.watson.collection_id,

    // note: no JSON.stringify needed with addJsonDocument()
    file: { 
        "ocorrencia_id": 9001
    }
}, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
    }

    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Nathan Friedly, I deleted my answer because yours is more complete and have the last update with best practicies. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you have is because of a missing content type (which defaults to `text/plain`). When you provide the document to upload as a string, you need to provide the content type and a filename along with it. In this instance, you can try using the following for your purpose

```
discovery.addDocument({
  //other required parameters 
  file: {
    value: JSON.stringify({ "ocorrencia_id": 9001 }),
    options: {
      filename: "some_file_name",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }
  } 
}, callbackFn)
```

Comment: I see... that does not seem to appear in the documentation. I'll take a look at it later today; thanks.

Comment: BTW, it's the filename, not the contentType that makes this work. But, the Node.js SDK now has .addJsonDocument() and .updateJsonDocument() that make it a bit more straightforward.