# Convert HTML source code to read stream

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently I'm working on a function which involve html template.

What this function does is to generate a dynamic template, and convert it into an image. As my understanding and what I R&D so far, it require to be a read stream before it able to convert into an image file.

So far, i manage to do it like this

```
fs.writeFile('sample.html', '<html>...</html>', function(err){
    fs.createReadStream('sample.html')
      .pipe(convert()) //function from html-convert npm package
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.png'))
});
```

Is there anyway to do this other than create a new file just for converting it to image?

Any help to this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: By converting to to image, do you mean the raw html code or the rendered html? I mean, What do you want to convert into image, just what you wrote or the rendered html?

Comment: yup it have to be displaying the rendered html... taking example of `<div>Hello world</div>` my image will be an empty image with Hello world text on it.

Comment: I think node-webshot is your best friend, I tried it and works well. Posted as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `node-webshot` https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot

```
var webshot = require('webshot');

webshot('<html><body>Hello World</body></html>', 'hello_world.png', {siteType:'html'}, function(err) {

});
```

**UPDATE**

If you want the screenshot of rendered html as base64 you can do

```
var renderStream = webshot('<html><body>Hello World</body></html>', {siteType:'html'});

renderStream.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString('base64'));
});
```

Comment: this work well. thanks. one extra question. If I want base64 string of the image instead of write into a file, is that possible with this plugin

Comment: Try this, 
var renderStream = webshot('<html><body>Hello World</body></html>', {siteType:'html'});

renderStream.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString('base64'));
});

Comment: No issues buddy, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

answer taken from [How to create streams from string in Node.Js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755997/how-to-create-streams-from-string-in-node-js)

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var s = new Readable();
s.push('<html>...</html>');
s.push(null)
.pipe(convert()) //function from html-convert npm package
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.png'))
});
```