# How to create a readStream from bytes in memory?

Tags: node.js, stream, fs, nodejs-stream

All of the examples of stream creation I have encountered are centered around file.  I am working with an interface that requires me to pipe a read stream to a write stream.  My input is raw bytes I have in memory, not a file.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

How to accomplish ^^^ by passing in 'raw bytes' instead of a file descriptor?

Comment: you can pass a Buffer too https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Answer (score 3):

This is what I got working (from [How to create streams from string in Node.Js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755997/how-to-create-streams-from-string-in-node-js)):

```
streamFromString(raw) {
    const Readable = require('stream').Readable;
    const s = new Readable();
    s._read = function noop() {};
    s.push(raw);
    s.push(null);
    return s;
  }
```