# Creating a Readable Stream to use with FormData

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using an [API to upload a CSV file](https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/import-responses). I create the CSV file in memory from a String and upload it using the `request` module. However, I'm having trouble creating the Readable Stream from the String. I followed a SO answer on [How to create streams from string in Node.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22085851/2900738). Here is my code for that solution:

```
var importResponse = function(csv, callback){
    stringify(csv, function(err, output){

        const s = new Readable();
        s._read = () => {}; 
        s.push(output);
        s.push(null);

        request.post({
          headers: {'X-API-TOKEN':token, 'content-type' : 'multipart/form-data'},
          url: 'https://ca1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseimports',
          formData: {
            surveyId: 'SV_123',
            file: {
                value: s,
                options: {
                    contentType: 'text/csv; charset=utf-8'
                }
            }
          }
        }, function(err, res, body){
            if(err || res.statusCode !== 200){
              console.log(err || "Error status code: " + res.statusCode);
              console.log(body);
              return;
            }
        });
    });

}
```

The `csv` variable looks like `[["QID1","QID2"],["1","2"]]` and the output from stringify looks like `"QID1,QID2\n,1,2\n"`.

This solution gives me the error `Unexpected end of input`

```
{"meta":{"httpStatus":"400 - Bad Request","error":{"errorMessage":"Unexpected end of input"}}}
```

If instead I use `memfs`, it works fine

```
const fs = require('memfs');

var importResponse = function(csv, callback){
    stringify(csv, function(err, output){
        // Create file in memory
        fs.writeFileSync('/data.csv', output); 

        request.post({
          headers: {'X-API-TOKEN':token, 'content-type' : 'multipart/form-data'},
          url: 'https://ca1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseimports',
          formData: {
            surveyId: 'SV_123',
            file: {
                value: fs.createReadStream('/data.csv'),
                options: {
                    contentType: 'text/csv; charset=utf-8'
                }
            }
          }
        }, function(err, res, body){
            if(err || res.statusCode !== 200){
              console.log(err || "Error status code: " + res.statusCode);
              console.log(body);
              return;
            }
        });
    });

}
```

How can I convert the output from `stringify` to a Stream that I can use to upload via the api?

Comment: Just so we know for sure, what is `stringify` coming from? Do you have a specific package you're requiring?

Comment: It looks like `csv-stringify` can create streams itself, FYI. You can probably just pass `stringify(csv)` directly as the "file" stream.

Comment: @Jacob yep, this fixed it. Changed my code to `var output = stringify(csv);` and it works now. Also changed the stringify module to the synchronous one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the `request` library. You may be coming across this caveat as documented in their [readme](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/README.md#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads):

```
// Pass optional meta-data with an 'options' object with style: {value: DATA, options: OPTIONS}
// Use case: for some types of streams, you'll need to provide "file"-related information manually.
// See the `form-data` README for more information about options: https://github.com/form-data/form-data
custom_file: {
  value:  fs.createReadStream('/dev/urandom'),
  options: {
    filename: 'topsecret.jpg',
    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
  }
}
```

Since you're using a non-file stream, simply providing a dummy filename should work:

```
request.post({
  headers: {'X-API-TOKEN':token, 'content-type' : 'multipart/form-data'},
  url: 'https://ca1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseimports',
  formData: {
    surveyId: 'SV_123',
    file: {
      value: s,
      options: {
        contentType: 'text/csv; charset=utf-8',
        filename: 'dummy.csv'
      }
    }
  }
}, function(err, res, body){
  if(err || res.statusCode !== 200){
    console.log(err || "Error status code: " + res.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, I tried adding the filename (had it there previously), but it still doesn't work. I'm wondering if the problem is with `Stringify`. I thought maybe that their was a new line character at the end of the string might have been causing it, but it wasn't. I'm not sure if it is a problem with `Stringify` and `memfs` "fixes" the problem when saving, or if the stream itself is wrong and not necessarily the content... if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that is the package. Sorry should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The sample snippet is incorrect or possibly outdated for current node versions. A really easy way to implement your readable:

```
const s = new Readable({
  encoding: 'utf8',
  read(size) {
    // Possibly respect the requested size to make for a good consumer experience
    // Otherwise:
    this.push(output, 'utf8');
    this.push(null); // This signals that there's no more data.
  }
});
```

Here's how you can respect the wishes of the reader:

```
let data = output;
const s = new Readable({
  encoding: 'utf8',
  read(size) {
    let wantsMore = true;
    while (wantsMore) {
      const chunk = data.slice(0, size);          
      if (!chunk) {
        return void this.push(null);            
      }

      wantsMore = this.push(chunk, 'utf8');
      data = data.slice(size);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reploy. I tried adding your snippet in place of the previous one, still received the same `Unexpected end of input` error.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake on signaling EOF. Try my update.

Comment: Added some notes on encoding. This is bizarre.

Comment: I think I figured it out after noticing you were using `request`. It's weird about "file" uploads. See the other answer.

Comment: (leaving this up for now in case there's also a problem with the stream, but it's probably the other answer).