# Using upload on basic-ftp, other possible uses

Tags: javascript, fs

I've been using https://github.com/patrickjuchli/basic-ftp

There code that I've been working on, and have a problem with using the upload.
the standard code is
`await client.upload(fs.createReadStream("README.md"), "README.md")`

the `README.md` on `fs.createReadStream("README.md")` is the file that is already at the directory

but on the code that I'm working on is generated on the javascript like this:

```
const os = require('os');

const output = []

const data = [{subject:'Math', grade: 85},{subject:'Art', grade: 80},..]

data.forEach((d) => {
  output.push(
    d.subject+ "\t"
    + d.grade+ "\n");
});

var dataTXT = output.join(os.EOL);

await client.upload(dataTXT , "filename.txt")
```

the problem is, the file that is sent was empty.

is there another way of implementing it, or I have to use `fs.createReadStream`
but there is no file/data that is can provide because is still on the code.
And I can't do `fs.writeFile` because of this code will be launch of a server later on.

Comment: I don't knew the API but I notice you're supposed to call `client.access` to connect to an FTP server before calling `client.upload`. Have you done so, was the empty file that was sent retrieved on the FTP server?

Comment: And if that's not the problem then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755997/how-to-create-streams-from-string-in-node-js) describes how to build ReadableStreams from strings (also "don't knew" -> "didn't know", yuk... too late to edit)